# How to best read a file and convert to a spark sqlContext dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to read a tab separated file with no header (sample rows as below)

```
196 242 3   881250949
186 302 3   891717742
```

I have 2 solutions to read the file and convert it to dataset. Can anybody tell me which is the better solution and why?

Solution1

```
final case class Movie(movieID: Int)

import spark.implicits._

val moviesDS1 = spark.sparkContext.textFile("file path")
                .map(x => Movie(x.split("\t")(1).toInt))
                .toDS
                .select("movieID")
```

Solution 2

```
final case class Movie(movieID: Int, Somenum1:Int, Somenum2: Int, Somenum3:Int)

import spark.implicits._
var movieSchema = Encoders.product[Movie].schema

val moviesDS2 = spark.read.options(Map("delimiter" -> "\t"))
                .schema(movieSchema)
                .csv("file path")
                .select("movieID")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Solution 2 is a always going to be minimum 5x faster than Solution 1.
- Solution 2 also provides an implicit validation against your input
  data and marks all the column values null if there is single a schema
  mismatch.
- Solution 2 also uses advance APIs which gives your Dataframes alike Solution first loads the data as RDD and then transforms it to DataSet.

Comment: @QuickSilver Thanks for the answer. What is the use case of the first solution then? The reason why I found the first solution easier was, if only a few columns of the file are required, I don't have to create a case class with all columns in the dataset.

Comment: Only reason to use the first solution which I can see is if you are stuck at old version of Spark and cannot upgrade it.
Please also upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Ok let have a small test to know which is better,

```
 final case class Movie(movieID: Int)
  exec {

    import spark.implicits._

    val moviesDS1 = spark.sparkContext.textFile("mydata.csv/Movies.csv").toDS()
      .map { x => {
        Movie(x.split("\t")(0).toInt)

      }
      }
      .select("movieID").show(false)
   // moviesDS1.show(false)
  }
  final case class Movie1(movieID: Int, Somenum1: Int, Somenum2: Int, Somenum3: Int)
  exec {
    var movieSchema = Encoders.product[Movie1].schema

    val moviesDS2 = spark.read.options(Map("delimiter" -> "\t"))
      .schema(movieSchema)
      .csv("mydata.csv/Movies.csv")
      .select("movieID")
    moviesDS2.show(false)
  }
```

where exec metthod will measure time in nano seconds...

```
  /**
    *
    * @param f
    * @tparam T
    * @return
    */
  def exec[T](f: => T) = {

    val starttime = System.nanoTime()
    println("t = " + f)
    val endtime = System.nanoTime()
    val elapsedTime = (endtime - starttime)
    //    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
    //    val convertToSeconds = TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(elapsedTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
    println("time Elapsed " + elapsedTime)
  }
```

Result :

```
+-------+
|movieID|
+-------+
|196    |
|186    |
+-------+

t = ()
time Elapsed 5053611258
+-------+
|movieID|
+-------+
|196    |
|186    |
+-------+

t = ()
time Elapsed 573163989
```

#### Conclusion :

As per numbers second approach is faster/optimized (since 573163989 nano sec <  5053611258 nano sec) than first approach.

Solution 1 We have to take care of parsing & mapping to corresponding classes where as in Solution 2 it eliminates low level parsing data & mapping data to case classes.

So solution 2 is better option.

So @QuickSilvers answer is right with this test case.